# Include | in url without url encoding it using NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl, url-encoding

I am using an API that needs the `|` character in the URL. I tried changing that character to `%7C`, but the API rejects it. Now the issue is `NSURLConnection` gives me this if I include a `|` in the url:

```
 NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x610000272bc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000247b60 "bad URL"}
```

How can include the `|` in my URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't: the pipe character is a so called unsafe character and must always be percent escaped to form a valid URL. See [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for the syntax of a valid URL.

You should contact the developers of the service you are using and ask them to change this peculiarity of their API's behavior.